# How to get authenticated user on serializer class for validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project using django-rest-framework. In my API view, an authenticated user can create other users. But, only five. Then if there are five users registered by one user, I want to send him in the response that hit the limit. Then, I need to get on my serializer the authenticated user but, I can't find a way to pass it from my ModelViewSet to my serializer.

This is my code:

View:

```
class ChildUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildUserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    authentication_classes = (
        TokenAuthentication,
    )
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticated,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        account_group = self.request.user.userprofile.get_account_group

        mobile_number = serializer.data.get('mobile_number')
        password = serializer.data.get('password')
        user = serializer.save()
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        # Generate user profile
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            mobile_number=mobile_number,
            user_type=CHILD,
            related_account_group=account_group,
        )
```

Serializer:

```
class ChildUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'mobile_number',
        )

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that the start is before the stop.
        """
        # Get authenticated user for raise hit limit validation



    def validate_email(self, value):
        if User.objects.filter(email=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This field must be unique.")
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = generate_unique_username(
            u'{0}{1}'.format(
                validated_data['first_name'],
                validated_data['last_name'],
            )
        )

        user = User(
            username=username,
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Then, in the `def validate(self, data)` function of my serializer, I want to get the currently authenticated user.

How can I pass the request.user from my APIView to my serializer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found an even easier way of accomplishing this! It turns out that Rest Framework's `GenericAPIView` base class (from which all of Rest Framework's generic `View` classes descend) [includes a function called `get_serializer_context()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3e1687282ba39b0166b7c17e39cdd3a2be7e2bc3/rest_framework/generics.py#L131):

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    """
    Extra context provided to the serializer class.
    """
    return {
        'request': self.request,
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

As you can see, the returned `context` object contains the same `request` object that the View receives. This object then gets set [when the serializer is initialized](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3e1687282ba39b0166b7c17e39cdd3a2be7e2bc3/rest_framework/generics.py#L104):

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
    deserializing input, and for serializing output.
    """
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thus to access the user who made the request, you just need to call `self.context['request'].user` from within your Serializer's `validate_` function:

```
class TemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_parent(self, value):
        print(self.context['request'].user)

        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Template
```

And the best part is that you don't have to override anything in your `ModelViewSet`, they can stay as simple as you want them to:

```
class TemplateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TemplateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
```

Answer (score 7):

In your views when you initialize serializer like

`serializer = ChildUserSerializer(data=request.DATA,context={'request':request})`

,send a context which contains request.Then in Serializers inside function call

`request=self.context['request']`

Then you can access `request.user`.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass additional context to your serializer with `serializer = ChildUserSerializer(data, context={'request': request})`. You can then access the authenticated user via `request.user` within your serializer validation method.

Answer (score 4):

In djangorestframework > 3.2.4 the `rest_framework.generic.GenericAPIView` class includes the http request by default in the serializer context.

So inside your serializer you can access it by: `self.context['request']` and the user `self.context['request'].user`

So your ChildUserSerializer will look like:

```
class ChildUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField()
    ....
    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that the start is before the stop.
        """
        # Get authenticated user for raise hit limit validation
        user = self.context['request'].user
        # do something with the user here
    def validate_email(self, value):
        if User.objects.filter(email=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This field must be unique.")
        return value
    ...
```

Comment: `user = self.context['request'].user` this line will cause `error`